# Upload picture / photo/ image facebook (android)

Tags: android, facebook, upload, photo, image

I'm using the official Facebook library and I publish photos perfectly.
But I've a doubt. When you post for first time, the image appears in the message above the wall. But when you post for second time, it doesn't create a new post, the previous post is edited and says "2 pictures added".

If the post is located at the bottom of the wall, and re-post a photo, we will not see any message at the top, will be released in the inner message. This will be as hidden.
Can you create a new post every time I upload a photo? How is it possible?

I share with you my code works also anyone can help. Thank you.

#### OnClick:

```
mFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
mFacebook.authorize(Principal.this, new String[]{ "user_photos,publish_checkins,publish_actions,publish_stream"},new DialogListener() {
@Override
public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
    postImageonWall();
     }
 @Override
 public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
     }
 @Override
 public void onError(DialogError e) {
     }
 @Override
 public void onCancel() {
     }
  });
```

#### PostWall:

```
public void postImageonWall() {

        byte[] data = null;

          Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fotomontatgeInSD);
          ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
          data = baos.toByteArray();


          Bundle params = new Bundle();
          params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, mFacebook.getAccessToken());
          params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
          params.putByteArray("picture", data);

          AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
          mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);
 }


public class SampleUploadListener extends BaseRequestListener {

 public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
     try {
         // process the response here: (executed in background thread)
         Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Response: " + response.toString());
         JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
         final String src = json.getString("src");

         // then post the processed result back to the UI thread
         // if we do not do this, an runtime exception will be generated
         // e.g. "CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original
         // thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

     } catch (JSONException e) {
         Log.w("Facebook-Example", "JSON Error in response");
     } catch (FacebookError e) {
         Log.w("Facebook-Example", "Facebook Error: " + e.getMessage());
     }
 }

 @Override
 public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }
}
```

**I just discovered that the new facebook design solves this problem.**

Comment: Hey can someone help me why am getting this error when following the above mentioned code error:02-16 08:05:46.021: V/Facebook(5398): Facebook{"error_code":101,"error_msg":"Invalid API key","request_args":[{"key":"method","value":"photos.upload"},{"key":"format","value":"json"}]}

Comment: your api key is not valid so please see you have mentioned proper api key or not

Comment: @ephramd Have you found out a solution to this yet?

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your code like:

```
mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);
```

Answer (score 0):

private void sharePhotoToFacebook() {
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.f1);

```
    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(image)
            .build();

    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
            .addPhoto(photo)
            .build();

    ShareApi.share(content, null);

}
```